# How to get an instance in django middleware?

Tags: python, django

I want to write a visit saver. My logic: I get request to specific view in middleware and set the data up in the redis. How can I get the instance of view?

My models.py

```
class HitPoint(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField('ip', protocol='both', unpack_ipv4=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.post)
```

And my custom middleware:

```
class MultipleProxyMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # PostDetail is CBV with slug.
        if view_func.__name__ == PostDetail.__name__:

            ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
            cache_name = f'post_{uuid.uuid4()}'
            cache.set(cache_name, {
             'ip': ip,
             # HOW CAN I GET THE INSTANCE OF POST?
             'post_id': ???,
             'created': now(),
            }, timeout=None)
```

Comment: Since this is tailored towards a specific view, I find it weird to write this as middleware. Usually middleware describes a set of tasks that is done *every* time. It looks to me that it is better to patch the `.get(..)` function in the view class for this.

Comment: Yes, I will do it in get method but in this example I just experiment with the middleware and want to know how to get an instance.

Comment: At that point, there is no instance, the instance is loaded *in* the view.

Comment: What method is better to use for it? dispatch or get?

Comment: Do your view method is receiving some kind of `url parameters`, say `slug`, `post_id` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could get your **url parameters** from `view_kwargs` argument of your middleware's `process_view` method. From that you can simply make a query to get the `id`. I am assuming that your `url` has a parameter named `slug`, then you can do something like this:

```
class MultipleProxyMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # PostDetail is CBV with slug.
        if view_func.__name__ == PostDetail.__name__:

            ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
            cache_name = f'post_{uuid.uuid4()}'

            post_id = Post.objects.get(slug=view_kwargs['slug']).id

            cache.set(cache_name, {
             'ip': ip,
             'post_id': post_id,
             'created': now(),
            }, timeout=None)
```